# Script to Batch Process InDesign Files, Compiling the File Name, and Data from a Table, Into a Spreadsheet

Tags: compiler-construction, batch-processing, adobe-indesign

Our spec sheets are made with InDesign, and there is a certain set of data points in one of the tables that we'd like to extract and put into a spreadsheet. We have thousands of these files though, so I'd like to see if there's a way to script an automated process.

I've used scripts for other tasks before, and even hacked at a few to create little solutions; but this one is well beyond me, and I just want to see if it's even possible.

The spec sheets are two pages. On page 2, there's a table with specs on it. It's a 2-column table, with section titles merged across both columns, and data cells have the data title on the left, and the data itself on the right. The data we need is the last 4 rows of the table. The header cell is "SHIPPING DATA", and then the four rows are weight, height, width, and depth. This data is always the last four rows of the table in every spec sheet.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible that a script could:

- either process a batch of files in a folder, or any open files,;;
- where per file, it could grab the name of the file and put that into a spreadsheet, row 1 column A;;
- then Find "SHIPPING DATA", select the 4 cells of data beneath that, and paste them into the spreadsheet row 1 columns B-E / might have to grab the data from those four cells one by one;;
- and then move to the next file, putting that same info into row 2

As I said, I don't even know if this would be possible, so I've not tried anything yet. If anyone has any ideas or thoughts on this, I'm all ears. Thanks!

Edit 01: Adding a screenshot that shows the file name and the portion of the table I refer to in my question.

[image]

Comment: The task to obtain the data from indd files is trivial. Most likely it can be done pretty easy. The data can be saved as a txt file, or csv, or json, etc. But the next task — to put the info into a 'spreadsheet' — it's need to clarify. What to you mean by 'spreadsheet'. MS Excel? Google Spreadsheet? Another indd file with a table? A new file or existed one?

Comment: Thanks Yuri! Sorry for the delayed response. The collected data will ultimately end up in an Excel spreadsheet. If a script solution works better with a Google doc, or some other table, then I could manually copy/paste the data into the Excel file after the script gets run.

Comment: Could you add a couple screenshots (or/and files) to see what your input and output data looks like?

Comment: I certainly can. I'll get some together and respond. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post to include a screenshot of the table I mention in my post.

Answer (score 0):

actually, InDesign provides data merging function

https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/indesign/using/data-merge.html

anyway, your idea is possible to do it in script

Comment: Thanks, but Data Merge is for bringing info IN to InDesign. My question is about extracting data.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```js
// dialog to select a folder if there are no open documents
if (app.documents.length == 0) {
    var from_folder = true;
    var folder = Folder.selectDialog('Select a folder with INDD files...');
    var files = folder.getFiles('*.indd');
    if (files.length == 0) {
        alert('No INDD files was found in the folder')
        exit();
    }
}

// if there are open documents process them
else {
    var from_folder = false;
    var files = app.documents;
}

// get the data from all tables each of the documents
var all_data = [];
for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    if (from_folder) var doc = app.open(files[i]);
    else var doc = files[i];
    var data = get_data_from_doc(doc);
    if (data) while (data.length) all_data.push(data.shift());
    if (from_folder) doc.close();
}

// if there is the data put it on the page of a new document
if (all_data.length > 0) {
    var doc = app.documents.add();
    var frame = doc.pages[0].textFrames.add();
    frame.geometricBounds = doc.pages[0].bounds;
    frame.contents = all_data.join('\r');
    frame.parentStory.texts[0].convertToTable();
} else {
    alert('No data was found');
}


// functions ------------------------------------------------------------------

function get_data_from_doc(doc) {
    var tables = get_all_tables_from_doc(doc);
    if (!tables || tables.length == 0) return;
    var data = get_data_from_all_tables(tables, doc);
    if (data && data.length > 0) return data;
}

function get_all_tables_from_doc(doc) {
    var stories = doc.stories;
    var all_tables = [];
    for (var i=0; i<stories.length; i++) {
        var tables = stories[i].tables;
        for (var j=0; j<tables.length; j++) all_tables.push(tables[j]);
    }
    if (all_tables.length > 0) return all_tables;
}

function get_data_from_all_tables(tables, doc) {
    var data = [];
    for (var i=0; i<tables.length; i++) {
        var table = tables[i];
        var data_row = get_data_from_table(table, doc);
        if (data_row) data.push(data_row);
    }
    if (data.length > 0) return data;
}

function get_data_from_table(table, doc) {
    var cell = get_cell_with_word(table, 'SHIPPING DATA');
    if (cell) {
        var index = cell.parentRow.index;
        var cell_1 = table.rows[index+1].cells[1].contents;
        var cell_2 = table.rows[index+2].cells[1].contents;
        var cell_3 = table.rows[index+3].cells[1].contents;
        var cell_4 = table.rows[index+4].cells[1].contents;
        return [doc.name, cell_1, cell_2, cell_3, cell_4].join('\t');
    }
}

function get_cell_with_word(table, word) {
    var cells = table.cells;
    for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
        if (cells[i].contents.toUpperCase() == word) return cells[i];
    }
}
```

It reads all the tables from all INDD documents (opened ones, or from selected folder if there are no open INDD documents). And makes a new INDD file with the table like this

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1.indd | 448 lbs | 58" | 40" | 43" |
| file2.indd | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| file3.indd | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Worked perfectly! On the first attempt, I was getting the missing link dialogues for each file, and then InDesign closed before the script created the new file with table. I turned off link checking in the preferences and tried the script again on the same folder and it worked without issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, Yuri! This works great as is, but if I need to in the future, is there anything I can tweak in the script that will make it search through subfolders as well?

Comment: The option to check all links can be turned off by a script by the way. As for subfolders, of course it can be done. There will be a some recursive function I suppose. Let me know if/when you need it.